# What is the size of integer in 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit processors/microcontrollers?

Tags: integer, microcontroller, processor, microprocessors

What is the size of integer in 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit processors/microcontrollers ?
I guess it depends on the internal accumulator/register size. But not sure.
Thanks

Comment: c# int is 32-bit on all CPUs on which C# can run.

Comment: It depends on the language and implementation.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ebf4a88-2bf5-448d-8abe-c63ad7938429/what-is-the-size-of-int-in-c?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @ebad86, does C# _run_ on any 8-bit CPUs that you know of? :-)

Comment: Not specifying a language I'm going to assume you're talking about C.  Typically the size of an integer follows the native register size: 8, 16, 32, 64, etc.  But it's really up to the C compiler - so there isn't a definitive answer.  As comments mention above, the platform/language can override everything.

Comment: FWIW, `int` in C is always has at least the range [-32767,32767].

Comment: Ok - so no 8-bit ints in C.  Should be -32768 for a min value though?

Comment: @Kirk: no, it's -32767 to account for the other two allowed encodings of negative numbers, both of which have plus _and_ minus zero, so lose -32768.

Comment: It's not true that int is only 16 bit! In the 32 bit environments int is 32 bits! This behavior was not extended to the 64 bit environment! Try this code: int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(char)*8);
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(short int)*8);
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(int)*8);
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(long)*8);
}

Answer (score 11):

I'm only aware of one programming language that defines an `integer` data type, but it's seldom used for 8 and 16-bit architectures.  C is the most widely used language for programming 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit architectures, so I assume you are looking for an answer in the context of C.

There are several "integer" data types in C: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc..., but I will assume what you really mean is the `int` data type.

The size of an `int` is not defined by the architecture, it is defined by the the C programming language specification, and it's extremely vague.

> A  ‘‘plain’’ `int` object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment (large enough to contain any value in the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` as defined in the header `<limits.h>`).

I interpret this to mean it is determined by the implementation of the compiler.

You can find the latest publicly available version of the C11 standard (at the time of writing this answer) here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html.

Here are some tests I ran to help answer this question:

- On an 8-bit Atmel AVR Arduino, `sizeof(int)` returns 2 (e.g. 16-bits) when compiled with GCC 4.3.2 (WinAVR 20081205)
- Don't have a 16-bit MCU or compiler, sorry!
- On a 32-bit ARM Cortex-M MCU, `sizeof(int)` returns 4 (e.g. 32-bits) when compiled with GCC 4.9.2.
- On a 64-bit Intel Core i7 CPU, `sizeof(int)` returns 4 (e.g. 32-bits) regardless of whether it is compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit. Tested with both Visual Studio 2013 and GCC 4.9.2.

A more interesting answer would be why those values were chosen.

Answer (score 2):

**C:**

Integer is defined by the c-standard as the "natural" data size. Implementers of C-Compilers for various platforms are allowed to set the integer size mostly at will. I think the idea behind all that is that int should reflect the data size which works best (fastest, ressource friendliest) for the given platform.

- Microchip XC8: 16 bit
- Microchip XC16: 16 bit
- Microchip XC32: 32 bit
- Keil: 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Integers can be of any size. The processor doesn't have much say in it. For example, in Java, int = 32 bits. In VB.NET, there exists Int16, Int32, and Int64, while the default Integer = 32 bits.

Comment: I always knew Java was limited but a 4-bit int? Really?