# Is it possible for the size of int data type to be 64 bits on a 32 bit architecture machine?

Tags: types

Can the size of int data type be greater than the size of machine architecture?

If not, then will a Java program not run on 16 bits machine architecture as the size of int in Java is 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the size of int data type be greater than the size of machine architecture?

Definitely. For example, on 8-bit Atmel AVR microcontrollers, the size of an int in C is 16 bits (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619947)). The size of an int depends on machine, vendor, OS ([target triplet](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet)) and programming language.

> Will a Java program not run on 16 bits machine
>   architecture as the size of int in Java is 32 bits?

No problem. It just means that the Java virtual machine for that platform would have to emulate 32-bit arithmetic, making Java slower on that platform.

In a language that compiles to machine code, the compiler would do the translation.

> Is it possible for the size of int data type to be 64 bits on a 32 bit architecture machine?

In principle, yes, but probably not likely. And not in Java, as you say.